# Coffee brewing methods - scientific analysis?

Tags: coffee, resources

Can anyone point out websites or academic articles analyzing coffee brewing methods?

I can easily identify taste differences between the various methods, but I'd like to know which ones are comparable and what variables are most important.

Methods:

```
drip
cold-brew (toddy)
pour-over
french press
other?
```

<del>espresso</del>

Beans:

```
type (arabica, robusta, other?)
roast (light->dark, freshness)
ground (fineness, consistency)
```

You can read about all this stuff all over the internet, but it's all anecdotes.  I'd like to see, e.g., the results of mass spectroscopy given different processes.

Comment: This is *way* too broad a question.  The variables that affect espresso are almost completely different from those that affect pour-over.

Comment: Alright, remove espresso from that list; espresso depends on pressure and temperature of the water being pressed through, while the other methods cannot depend on pressure.  If you still think it's too broad, help me refine it further.

Comment: Also, note that I'm not asking for users to come up with their own experiments - I'm asking for references to published (academic?) literature.

Comment: This article from Gizmodo links to a company that makes refractometers specifically to measure particulate levels and pH balance of coffee. Good read, and lots of scientific looking charts related to coffee flavor. [Chasing the Perfect Cup of Coffee With Science](http://gizmodo.com/5642561/seeking-mojo-chasing-the-perfect-cup-of-coffee-through-science)

Comment: Related: We have quite an extensive Q&A on [manual drip coffee](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/11694/41), many of the principles of which would also apply to automatic drip. I do think that this question is pretty broad, but so are all [resources] questions; this one is at least focused on a fairly specific topic.

Comment: I did some cleanup on this old question. The link-only answers were no longer useful, except for one I converted to a comment. Since we have a special understanding with Coffee.SE to migrate all questions, I migrated a newer duplicate there instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is old, unanswered, and there is a better one at Coffee.SE -https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/5923/any-scientific-studies-on-time-versus-temperature-when-brewing-coffee